# In Google Sheets how do I search for a specific value in a column?

Tags: google-sheets

I've started working with Google Sheets.

I'm looking for a value that I believe exists in a specific column.
I know which column the value exists in.

How do I find the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to search for a value in a column range, and return the location of the cell.
I couldn't find an appropriate precedent in webapps, so this answer is adapted from [Google Spreadsheet Check From What Cell VLOOKUP() Returns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18375230/1330560). The difference in this case is that the search range does not begin with column A and/or Row#1.

Use this formula:
`=IFNA(ADDRESS(MATCH($B$1,$D$10:$D$16,0)+$B$6-1,$B$5,1),"No match")`

- "$B$1": value to search
- "$D$10:$D$16": range to search
- "$B$6": first row of data
- "$B$5": column number being searched.

---

**Sample**

[image: Sample]

---

**Logic**

- `MATCH` returns the row of the searched value in the search range. Since the search range doesn't necessary begin in row#1, you need to add the actual row on which the search range begins and then subtract one to derive the row  on which the searched value exists.
- `ADDRESS(row, column, abs)` returns the  cell address. In this case, the row is derived from "MATCH", and the column is entered manually. `abs` indicated whether the format should be "A1" or "R1C1", the formula opts for "A1".